# How can i use role based s3 access for S3tiff image in geoserver?

Tags: amazon-s3, geoserver

> It's working with credentials if u provide or set in env variable.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more information. For example, what have you tried and what problems are you experiencing? What is 'geoserver' and how does it interact with Amazon S3? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Might need to extend the S3tiff class to implement it